# js css list with scroll and autoselect?

Tags: jquery, css, list

I would like to make a list where the parent div's height is fixed and I can navigate in the list with mouse scroll (inside the div). The list item in the center of the div (vertically) is auto-selected. Here is an image what I found: http://www.jqueryscript.net/images/iOS-7-Style-jQuery-3D-Animated-Value-Selector-Drumjs.jpg
This is what I would like to make with html, css, js. Just I would like to fin a source file or examples or guide.

Comment: put your codes here sir..

Comment: what do you mean the list item is auto-selected? are we talking for a `ul` or what?

Comment: There is no codes. I know html and css but not really js. So I searching for exmaples or source files. Thanks

Comment: Yes I thougt an ul. The auto-select is just a mark with a border or something like this.

Comment: Wait so you want a list with an item pre-selected (i.e. Before the user has clicked the list), but you don't want it to be a dropdown? If I'm assuming this correctly, you want a Radio Button list, styled with css to be scrollable (and pretty) with a pre-selected item... Right?

Comment: That would be ideal, but no problem if this not work. Oh I think my question is too complicate for my english :) Sorry. I have to look for an example...

Comment: OK, I edited the question with a pic

Comment: Yes Mr. E. I want something like this. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a datepicker that works more or less like ios one.
http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/
(and this: https://code.google.com/p/mobiscroll/)
then, if you want a menu or something similiar, you can start from this and edit by yourself.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I can use what I found in these links.